# How to correctly use the AlarmManager class to execute a task at fixed intervals?

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

I'm trying to make an app which must execute a certain task at fixed intervals. After much research and trying I figured it's better to use the AlarmManager class due to its efficiency at memory and battery usage instead of running a timer inside a service.

There are some aspects now that I'me having problem with.
One is how should I get access to the alarm object that is been created on a previous run in order to be able to cancel it?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MyService.class);
PendignIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(getActivity(), 0, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() +
                            20000, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, pintent);
```

There is way to know if the alarm has been set or not but it can't give you the alarm itself.

```
boolean alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getService(getActivity(), 0, new Intent(getActivity(), MyService.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
if(alarmUp){
   //How to cancel the alarm
}else {
   Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Alarm not running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes youcan cancel alarm based on PendingIntent like this-

```
AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent alarmintent1=new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent sender1=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(SpeedMotors.this, 100, alarmintent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);

    try {
        am.cancel(sender1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("ex....."+e);
    }

    Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 5);


    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 1000*10, sender1);
    System.out.println("alarm set...........");
```

try it ll help you.

Answer (score 1):

Registration and cancellation in alarm manager is based on pending intent. If you create pending intent with same arguments, You can access same alarm.